# How to call a built dll file in LabVIEW from c#?

Tags: c#, labview

I have tried dllimport and extern command without any success. Searched the net for some examples, which just added more to my confusion :-). Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Static void Main (string[] args)
{
CallLVSharedVar
}

[DllImport(@"SharedLibtoCSharp.dll")]
private extern static void CallLVSharedVar([MarshalAS(UnmanagedType.
```

Comment: You need to use P/Invoke. Show us what you've tried and what the problem is and we might be able to help.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for your reply. Here is what I have tried:Static void Main (string[] args)
{
CallLVSharedVar
}
 
[DllImport(@"SharedLibtoCSharp.dll")]
private extern static void CallLVSharedVar([MarshalAS(UnmanagedType.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to include this information rather than putting it in a comment.

Comment: @Nick You are right. New guy here. ^_^

Comment: It doesn't look that code would compile... What other issues are you having? Do you have the declaration of the function you're looking to import?

Comment: yes, i do have declaration issues as well ;)

Comment: I'm trying to help here but you're not making it very easy! In order to help I'll need to see the declaration of the function you're trying to import.

Comment: Just insert the entire code you are using for declaration and calling/invoking the dll and we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LabVIEW also has the ability to create .NET assemblies, so if you have the VI source code, you could do that instead... 
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvhowto/building_a_net_assembly/